# Can thaumcraft bosses (mobs that drop lootbags) spawn from vanilla spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

I am playing modded minecraft 1.7.10 (I am using thaumcraft 4.2) and I am planning on making a big blaze farm. And I would like to set up a little lottery for my basemates. I would also like to use vanilla spawners. Can blazes spawned from vanilla spawners drop lootbags? If so that would be amazing there could be a ton more prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bunch of testing and found out they do. Though I would be glad if you answered me the rate at which they drop.